# Twig include CSS or Java Script

Tags: symfony, twig

I am completely new to Twig. I have a Twig project, but I do not manage to configure paths to css and js file in the project. 
The packages I have installed (as in the composer.json file) are:

```
     "require": {
    "twig/twig": "~1.0",
    "symfony/twig-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/asset": "^3.1",
    "symfony/templating": "^3.1",
    "symfony/yaml": "^3.1"
}
```

In the project I have a folder "vendor" (where all these packages are found) and folder "web", in which I want to put my folders "views", "resources/images" and "resources/styles".

However, when I try to run in cmd the command:

```
    php app/console assets:install web --symlink
```

I get the error: Could not open input file: app/console.

What should I do to include a css file, or image, or js file in the most accurate way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Symfony version 3.x it was changed from `app/console` to `bin/console`.

Additionally you should follow the 3.x [installation guide](https://symfony.com/download) for Symfony Installer or for [composer installation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html#creating-symfony-applications-with-composer) to ensure you have the desired library and bundles. As the console and directory structure are not automatically created when using `Composer` alone.

Your composer should consist of pretty much only `symfony/framework-standard-edition` instead of the individual components. Otherwise you will need to install the components manually, and setup any other dependencies and configurations to get them all to work together.  http://symfony.com/components

Comment: So, your advice is to start by creating a project with Symphony installer and then adding Twig to it, not by just starting Composer and then installing Twig?

As for bin/console, there is probably something wrong with the components in my project,as it returns the same error

Comment: Twig comes as a part of the symfony framework. As you're trying to use Symfony to manage your assets with the Symfony console (`bin/console`), it would be far easier to use the entire framework properly installed. Managing the individual components is a hassle (which is where you're at now). For example the twig-bundle can not be used without the `Http-Kernel` component and `Framework Bundle`. EG: `symfony/symfony-standard`. And can not be used without registering the bundle in your `app/AppKernel.php` file. See: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/app/AppKernel.php

Comment: As for using twig in general, it is perfectly fine as a standalone package. Just not using Symfony to manage your asset files, as it appears that Symfony was not properly installed in order to provide you with the `console` See: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/bin/console